# Como envio arreglo con un insert

Tags: php, sql-server

quiero hacer un insert a la base de datos , pero los datos que deseo enviar son arreglos , queria saber si me ayudan a como mandar esos arreglos al INSERT estoy trabajando con PHP y SQLServer
esta es la tabla que tengo y depende los insumos que se seleccionen quiero mandarlos a la BD
[image]

si conocen algún manual o blog en el que pueda ayudarme les agradecería

Comment: Tienes que sacar los valores del arreglo, asignarlos a variables por ejemplo  y construir  el `INSERT` usando esas variables. El mismo Manual de PHP  explica cómo leer un arreglo...

Comment: Por lo que veo, me suena a que no es un insert si no muchos insert, necesitas mostrar detalle de la tabla para saber cómo los estás insertando